# VBA loop merging cells in specific range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, merge

I have a specified range and want to merge the cells A-D per row. I'm not sure which loop would be the best, and have messed around with different ones and the problem I have run into, is either an object-defined error or merging the entire range into one cell.

```
Sub Merge()

Dim EndRangeRE As Range
Dim EndRangeNRE As Range
Dim rngall As Range
Dim StartRangeNRE As Range
Dim StartRangeRE As Range
Dim looprng As Range

Sheets("{Activity} 7300-1input template").Activate
Set rngall = Sheets("{Activity} 7300-1input template").UsedRange
Set EndRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="10. Other Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set EndRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Non-Recurring Costs",LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues,LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set looprng = Sheets("{Activity} 7300-1input template").Range(StartRangeNRE, EndRangeRE)

For Each Row In looprng
    Cells(0, 4).Merge
Next Row

End Sub
```

This one gives me an error and I'm not sure how to specify to do each row, A:D merge and next row.  Would it be a do loop? I'm very open to the easiest way to make this happen so suggestions are gladly welcomed (I'm not too experienced in coding so anything to help me learn!).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below incoropates Merging cells in columns "A:D" in your `looprng` range.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()

Dim EndRangeRE As Range
Dim EndRangeNRE As Range
Dim rngall As Range
Dim StartRangeNRE As Range
Dim StartRangeRE As Range
Dim looprng As Range
' 2 added object variables      
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim myRow As Range   

' set your worksheet object, don't need to Activate it
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("{Activity} 7300-1input template")    
Set rngall = Sht.UsedRange

Set EndRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="10. Other Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set EndRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeNRE = rngall.Find(What:="Non-Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
Set StartRangeRE = rngall.Find(What:="Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

Set looprng = Sht.Range(StartRangeNRE, EndRangeRE)

' merge cells in columns "A:D" in your range
For Each myRow In looprng.Rows
    Sht.Range(Sht.Range("A" & myRow.Row), Sht.Range("D" & myRow.Row)).Merge
Next myRow

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This will merge **A** through **D** for 100 rows:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    For i = 1 To 100
        Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).MergeCells = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

```
Sub ytrewq()
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).MergeCells = True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might be missing the purpose this time, he is looking to merge cells between 2x`Find` , to merge all cells between `"Non-Recurring Costs"` and `"10. Other Costs"`

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're after this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Merge()
    Dim EndRangeRE As Range, StartRangeNRE As Range
    Dim myRow As Range

    With Sheets("{Activity} 7300-1input template")
        With .UsedRange
            Set EndRangeRE = .Find(What:="10. Other Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
            Set StartRangeNRE = .Find(What:="Non-Recurring Costs", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        End With

        For Each myRow In .Range(StartRangeNRE, EndRangeRE).Rows
            .Rows(myRow.row).Resize(, 4).Merge
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

where I got rid of unused variables and use some `With-End With` block to reference multiple reference of the same object

Answer (score 1):

Try This code :

```
 Sub test()
        'Get The Last non empty row
        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lastRow
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("A" & i & ":D" & i).Merge
        Next i

 End Sub
```